# Transform array to contain duplicate of each item

Tags: java, arrays

I have names in an array of Strings:

```
["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

I want to transform it to be:

```
["foo", "foo", "bar", "bar", "baz", "baz"]
```

My current solution:

```
String[] ns = new String[2 * names.length];
int i = 0;
for (String name : names)
{
    ns[i++] = name;
    ns[i++] = name;
}
```

Is there a cleaner solution? In particular, I think the duplicated assignment is poorly done.

Comment: What metrics are you using for determine a "clean" solution?  Readability?  Time efficiency?

Comment: Keeping your approach, if you just want to avoid the duplicated assignement, you can substitute it with a single `ns[i++] = ns[i++] = name;`
instruction. Or you are looking for a different approach?

Comment: I do not think this can be any more time efficient. Can it? I mean mostly readability.

Comment: @Spock that is an interesting approach that is new to me. However, I think I am going to use Elliott Frisch's solution.

Comment: Since you are looking for feedback on improving specific aspect of working code, you could see if [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is a better fit for your question.

Comment: Thank you @ryanyuyu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using Java 8+, you could use a `Stream` - `flatMap` every element to a two element stream and then collect to a `List` before converting back to an array. Like,

```
String[] names = { "foo", "bar", "baz" };
String[] ns = Stream.of(names).flatMap(s -> Stream.of(s, s))
        .collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new String[] {});
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit cleaner, perhaps:

```
String[] ns = new String[2 * names.length];
for (int i = 0; i < ns.length; i++)
    ns[i] = names[i / 2];
```